# Simplify a promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

How to simplify this statement:

```
Foo.execSomething(k,v).then(function(){/*do nothing*/},(err) => {
  console.log(err)
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
});
```

I call those suffix (starting from `.then`) a lot, I don't care if it's succeed, but I care when it's failed, is there simpler way to do it?

Comment: Just remove the .then(...), .catch() will be fired with any rejection or exception.

Comment: Ah, so `.then` is not required at all?

Comment: @Kokizzu As noted in the comment, it does nothing.

Comment: It's not required, the first callback provided will be executed WHEN the promise(s) are resolved, the second callback will be executed WHEN any promise gets rejected. .catch() only have one callback that will be called if any promise of the upperchain is rejected or threw an exception.

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `Foo.execSomething(k,v).catch(console.log).catch(console.log)`. Go figure out whether you need that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `then` function in a Promise Object has to parameters, the first parameter is to handle when success, and the second is to handle error. But it's not suggest to catch error in `then` method.
Those two are same(I use console.log as error handler):

```
// first way:
Promise.reject('error').then(success => {}, err => console.log(err));
// console logs "error"

// second way
Promise.reject('error').catch(err => console.log(err));
// console logs "error"

// your code 
Promise.reject('error').then(success => {}, err => console.log(err))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
// it will prints only a "error" in the console, so there are the same
```

so, if you do not care when it succeed, you could simplify your code like this:
`Foo.execSomething(k,v).catch(err => console.log)`

Answer (score 3):

How about *just* using the catch function?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

> The catch() method returns a Promise and deals with rejected cases only. It behaves the same as calling Promise.prototype.then(undefined, onRejected).